# Errors when trying to use getuikit with vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli-3, getuikit

I am trying to get the UIkit CSS framework to work with VueJS-based app.
I have included the framework with yarn, and the styling works fine.

However whenever I try to programmatically invoke any of UIkit components I get the error message `UIkit is not defined`.

Here are the extracts from my app files:

**main.js**

```
    import Vue from "vue";
    import App from "./App.vue";
    import router from "./router";

    import UIkit from 'uikit';
    import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons';

    UIkit.use(Icons);

    new Vue({
      router,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
```

**App.vue** (this is just added to the bottom of the file, without it the styling won't work)

```
<style lang="less">
  @import "../node_modules/uikit/src/less/uikit.theme.less";
</style>
```

And an example of problem causing code - in this case trying to open a modal window:

```
UIkit.modal('#mod-department-edit').show();
```

Thing to point out would be if I simply include the uikit framework by using  &  tags, either by local files or using cdn it all work fine.

So clearly I am missing something somewhere. Any idea what that might be?

Comment: If you're trying to use UIkit from within App.vue, you need to import it there as well.

Comment: @StephenThomas - I knew it would be something silly I missed. Thank you.